# how to use GPG to decrypt multiple files to a different directory

Tags: windows, gpg, encryption

I am trying to decrypt multiple files to a different directory keeping the existing filenames. When i run the below syntax it seems to decrypt them ok but it only ouputs to the screen. I would like to either output the files with the same name to a different directory or overwrite the exciting files with the same name. Can this be done with gpg?  Here is my syntax:

```
FOR %i in (C:\GPGFILES\*.gpg) do (gpg --batch --yes --passphrase key123 --decrypt "%i")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the `--output` argument.  If you don't tell it where to output the file, it will only print the output to the screen.

So:

```
FOR %i in (C:\GPGFILES\*.gpg) do (gpg --batch --yes --passphrase key123 --output "%i.txt" --decrypt "%i")
```